# How to show a particular post for the logged in user in a simple blog site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, list

The scenario is, I have simple Post table with just title & story. after posting a new post I want to show the post using my view page.I have write the method to display the post as follows:

```
  \\Post is the class name & item is the obj to bind it from the view form.
public List<Post> ViewPost(Post item)
    {
        using(var context=new TourBlogEntities1())
        {
            var post= from s in context.Posts
                      where s.PostID=item.PostID //showing error here.
                      select s;

            return post.ToList<Post>();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error saying 'can't convert the lambada expression to type string because its not a delegate type'.

Whats need to be done? some more information would also be helpfull, like I have a field name userid in post table, which I want to fill automatically by using the logging info. How can I do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your LINQ query replace:

```
where s.PostID = item.PostID
```

with:

```
where s.PostID == item.PostID
```

The `where` LINQ operator expects a boolean condition and not an assignment.

Comment: OPS! That's silly! I just didn't notice! Thanks mate! Can you help me with the other info plz?

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking in the second part of your question.

Comment: ok...The user had to log in to post, so he submitted his username & password to log in, now when he wants to post a story, I want to know the username by using the log in info. In general, I need to know the basic info of the currently logged in user. How can I do that? I used form authentication by the way.

Comment: You could retrieve the currently authenticated username using `User.Identity.Name` inside your controller action. Make sure your controller action is decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute to ensure that only authenticated users can call it.

Comment: I did mark the post action method as authorize. Thanks for all your help.